# Similar paradigms as readers-writers prob and producer-consumer prob

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, producer-consumer, overlapping, paradigms

for my Operating Systems Networking class, we must come up with a common paradign that is faced when developing operating systems and propose a solution to the paradigm. Some possible topics suggested in class were: Producer/Consumer problem, reader/writer problem and there was a third one, idk the name for it. It was something like this:

Protection of Private Data – When a user has personal or private data he must share with a network in order to get information, but doesn’t want his information to be released.
    -If a user must request a server for information and must provide some private data, the user tells his OS to request the information by sending a series or an array of data to the server. Some are actual data and some are fake. The server responds, handling each set of data as a separate request, it then returns the results and the OS picks the right one.

Example:
1)  Person A uses his phone which uses his GPS coordinates to locate the closest bank. The OS on the phone knows that if the GPS coordinates were to get out, this could be bad. The phone instead, sends a request to AT&T asking for the closest bank for the following locations: the actual location person A is at, as well as 3 other fake locations. AT&T has no way of telling which location is the true location and which are the fake ones and is therefore forced to treat each one as a separate request. The results are sent back to the phone and the phone uses only the result for the location that is correct.

Another problem one of my friends did last semester was DDoS. I was wondering if you guys new of any other problems,issues or paradigms that are still lurking about.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Seems like a Google search on *operating system design principles* would be a much more efficient way to obtain this information. We're not here to do your research for you.

Comment: As well as doing that, I thought I would ask as novice student of computers someone with more experience that might have an interesting one in mind. Thanks though